# Specify Filename in {httr} File Upload

Tags: r, curl, httr

I am trying to translate the following (working) curl query into {httr} code:

```
CURL=`which curl`
$CURL -H "Accept: application/json" \
      -F "token=TOKEN_TOKEN" \
      -F "content=file" \
      -F "action=import" \
      -F "record=1" \
      -F "field=file_upload" \
      -F "file=@old.txt;filename=new.txt" \
      https://somewhere.com/api/
```

The following does not work as the server ignores the `filename` when submitted as what amounts to an additional form element.

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://somewhere.com/api/",
  body = list(
    "token"    = "TOKEN_TOKEN",
    "content"  = "file",
    "action"   = "import",
    "record"   = "1",
    "field"    = "file_upload",
    "file"     = httr::upload_file("old.txt"),
    "filename" = "new.txt"
  ),
  encode = "multipart"
)
```

Is there some way to specify the new filename instead of having the filename inferred from the original file's name?

Comment: It doesn't look like the `httr::POST` supports this because it doesn't look like the underlying `curl` library supports this. I can't see an easy way to change the file name in the request. Does the API you are interacting with not have an alternate way to specify the file name you want to use?

Comment: The API does not provide a documented method to specify an alternate filename. The name is simply taken from the original file supplied to `httr::upload_file()`. When you say `curl` library are you talking about the {curl} R package or curl itself?

Comment: I'm taking about the `curl` R package. Specifically the code that can be found here https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/0d355776269b703824cd81efef52b4400e3397ca/src/form.c. The underlying C library does of course support alternative file names. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate file name specification is [now supported](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/pull/290).

## httr

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://somewhere.com/api/",
  body = list(
    "token"    = "TOKEN_TOKEN",
    "content"  = "file",
    "action"   = "import",
    "record"   = "1",
    "field"    = "file_upload",
    "file"     = curl::form_file("old.txt", name = "new.txt")
  ),
  encode = "multipart"
)
```

## httr2

```
httr2::request("https://somewhere.com/api/") %>% 
  httr2::req_body_multipart(
    token    = "TOKEN_TOKEN",
    content  = "file",
    action   = "import",
    record   = "1",
    field    = "file_upload",
    file     = curl::form_file("old.txt", name = "new.txt")
  ) %>% 
  httr2::req_perform()
```